# Add property to association in Entity Framework 5

Tags: many-to-many, associations, entity-framework-5

I had a pure junction table (to represent a many-to-many relationship) in my database. That is, a table with only two columns, each of them being a foreign-key, and them together composing the primary-key.

EF hid that complexity from me by not mapping this table to an entity, as expected; it was mapped as an Association.

Then I added a new column to this junction table in my database, and went on to Update Model From Database in the EDMX. But the table remained as an Association, not turning into an Entity with 3 properties.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is you need to delete the association first. Go to `Model Browser > Your Model > Associations`, find and delete the association. Then you can update the model and the table will show up as an entity.